# XPATH expression to select all elements who do not cotain a certain parent

Tags: php, xpath

I am using XPATH in PHP. Assume I have the following HTML

```
<div>
    <a>
        <img id='img1' src='src1' />
    </a>
    <div>
        <img id='img2' src='src2' />
    </div>
    <img id='img3' src='src3' />
    <div>
        <a>
            <img id='img4' src='src4' />
        </a>
    <div>
    <a>
        <div>
            <img id='img5' src='src5' />
        </div>
    <a>
</div>
```

I would like to write an XPATH expression that will select all `<img>` tags, that do not have `<a>` tags as direct parents.

So in the example above, only **img2**, **img3**, and **img5** should result from that expression's selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//img[not(parent::a)]
```

Give that a try.